# Triggering an activity resume

Tags: android, android-activity

I need to start a function when an activity is resumed. For example:

I have an activity A and in it, I start another called B. Then, when B is finished, it calls `finish()` and then A is resumed. But when A is resumed, I want to call a function to refresh some info so I need to know when A is resumed from another activity.

Is this possible in Android?

Comment: To better understand the process; are you pausing A while B is running?

Comment: Here is a link which may be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569830/get-result-from-an-activity-after-finish-in-an-android-unit-test

Answer (score 0):

There's a method you can override on Activity which unsurprisingly named [`onResume`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

When starting activity B, you should use the [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) method. It will then call on Activity A's onActivityResult() after finish() is called. See the doc on [Starting Activities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through Android basics.You can override onResume() method of activity 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume()