# Parcelable data unavailable when an Activity is created again after back button

Tags: java, android, android-activity, parcelable, oncreate

I have one ListActivity. It receives a parcelable object and saves it as a property.

The thing is that when you press one of ListView item another Activity shows up:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setHjClient((Client) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("hjClient"));
    setListAdapter(new ComplejoListAdapter(this, getHjClient().getComplejos()));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    //super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Complejo c = ((Complejo) l.getAdapter().getItem(position));
    Intent i = new Intent(this, ComplejoActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("session", getHjClient().getSession());
    i.putExtra("complejo", c);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Until here everything works as expected, but when I press back button, the OnCreate method is called again but now getIntent() is null so I didn't have my parcelable data that I need to fill my ListView so I receive a NullPointerException error.

How can I access that parcelable data when Activity shows up after I press back button?

Edited my onCreate method:

```
Client hjClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        setHjClient((Client) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("hjClient"));
        setListAdapter(new ComplejoListAdapter(this, getHjClient().getComplejos()));
    } else if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        setHjClient((Client) savedInstanceState.getParcelable("hjClient"));
        setListAdapter(new ComplejoListAdapter(this, getHjClient().getComplejos()));
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putParcelable("hjClient", getHjClient());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'Activity' sounds like it is destroyed (probably because of memory constraints).

This is a "classic" case of when Android says that you need to persist data in case events happen that are outside of your control. The best example of this is when a user is in your app and the phone rings. They leave your app and when they return, you should not expect the "state" to be saved.

You need to find a way to persist the parcelable data that you get from:

```
getIntent().getParcelableExtra("hjClient"))
```

That call should be to a "SharedPreferences" or other persistent data store.

This is not easy to implement because if you have other ways that a user could access this Activity then you need to account for that.

Another approach (mentioned in another answer but not well explained) is to bundle your data in the intent to start the next Activity, and then when that Activity is complete, pass back that data in 'onActivityForResult' by using 'setResult' as described here:

[Get result from an activity after finish(); in an Android unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569830/get-result-from-an-activity-after-finish-in-an-android-unit-test)

Then check the results for your data and re-populate your client object.

Bottom line: do not expect a user to be able to return to ANY activity in the state they last saw it without persisting the data to re-create that state.

Comment: The approach using startActivityForResult works for me. Thank you very much @Jim

Answer (score 0):

You can use [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)) instead of startActivity, and then send the Intent back when the other activity is finished.

Comment: It doesn't work also. When I press back button onCreate method is fired and getIndent() is null

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `onSaveInstanceState()` to save your data before the activity goes away.

Comment: savedInstanceState in onCreate method is null when I press back button