# Espresso: How can I test that the activity finished with result RESULT_OK?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-espresso

In my application, when the user clicks on a "Register" button, the RegisterActivity is launched. Once the user fills in the form, the details are posted to a web service and if registration succeeds, RegisterActivity finishes with `RESULT_OK`. This is summarized in the code sample below:

```java
public void submitRegistration() {

    showProgressDialog(R.string.registration, R.string.please_wait);  
    
    getWebApi().register(buildRegistrationFromUI(), new Callback<ApiResponse>() {

        @Override
        public void success(ApiResponse apiResponse, Response response) {     
            hideProgressDialog();
            setResult(RESULT_OK);
            finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            hideProgressDialog();
            showErrorDialog(ApiError.parse(error));
        }
    });
}
```

Using Espresso, how can I check that the activity finished with `setResult(RESULT_OK)`?

Please note: I do **NOT** want to create a mock intent. I want to check the intent result status.

Comment: [Looks like this has been answered already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569830/get-result-from-an-activity-after-finish-in-an-android-unit-test), using reflection to get the values from the activity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All the setResult(...) method does is to change the values of fields in the Activity class

```
 public final void setResult(int resultCode, Intent data) {
    synchronized (this) {
        mResultCode = resultCode;
        mResultData = data;
    }
}
```

So we can use Java Reflection to access the mResultCode field to test if the value has indeed been set to RESULT_OK.

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<ContactsActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(
        ContactsActivity.class);


@Test
public void testResultOk() throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    Field f = Activity.class.getDeclaredField("mResultCode"); //NoSuchFieldException
    f.setAccessible(true);
    int mResultCode = f.getInt(mActivityRule.getActivity());

    assertTrue("The result code is not ok. ", mResultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use an `ActivityTestRule` and get the Activity result like this:

```
assertThat(rule.getActivityResult(), hasResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK));
assertThat(rule.getActivityResult(), hasResultData(IntentMatchers.hasExtraWithKey(PickActivity.EXTRA_PICKED_NUMBER)));
```

Full example available [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/android-support-test/espresso/sample/src/androidTest/java/android/support/test/testapp/ActivityResultTest.java).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood the question correctly. However, on closing your activity, if the main application is still open you can check the activity result. You need to expose the result status in your application code and will have to write the view matcher to verify if it matches with the expected one.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [ActivityScenario](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/core/app/ActivityScenario) (or [ActivityScenarioRule](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/ext/junit/rules/ActivityScenarioRule)) as is the current recommendation in the Android Developers documentation (see the [Test your app's activities](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/testing) page), the [ActivityScenario](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/core/app/ActivityScenario) class offers a [getResult()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/core/app/ActivityScenario#getResult()) method which you can assert on as follows:

```kotlin
@Test
fun registration() {
    val activityScenario = ActivityScenario.launch(RegisterActivity::class.java)

    // TODO: execute some view actions which perform the registration

    // TODO: execute a view action which causes the activity to be finished

    assertEquals(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, activityScenario.result.resultCode)
}
```