# Is there a solution that access MainActivity from other Activity class?

Tags: java, android

I want to call function below.

```
mobileView.loadUrl("javascript:setUserId () ");
```

And mobileView is in MainActivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mobileView;
}
```

I want to call function above after SecondActivity is finished.

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...
    private void getUserId () {
        ...
        finish();
    }
}
```

And SecondActivity starts from AReceiver.

```
public class AReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ...
        Intent i = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        ...
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

And AReceiver is called by below code...

```
class MainActivity {
    ...
    private void userId () {
        ...
        intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                MainActivity.this, 
                alarmID, 
                intent, 
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
        alarmManager.set(
                AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
                mCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), 
                pendingIntent
        );
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

But I don't know how to access mobileView from SecondActivity.
Is there any solution?

---

What I've tried...

1. change variable from

```
private webView mobileView
```

to

```
public webView mobileView
```

2.
call from SecondActivity Using

```
MainActivity.mobileView
```

It doesn't work for me.

Comment: Maybe this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569830/get-result-from-an-activity-after-finish-in-an-android-unit-test

Comment: Are you started SecondActivity from MainActivity

Comment: no I started SecondActivity from another receiver extends BroadcastReceiver.....

Comment: Then you can use local broadcast manager or event bus and pass required data and info along with it and execute the required method. Checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager

Comment: Thank you! Hope you have a good day :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using local broad cast manager! :D
Thank you @Shripad Jadhav who help this answer.

Below description is solution! Hope it helpes somebody. :D

---

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView wv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)
            .registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("webview-filter"));
        ...
    }
    ...
    private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            mv.loadUrl("javascript: loadMainData ()");
        }
    };
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

SecondActivity.java

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private void someFunction () {
        sendMessage ();
    }
    ...
    private void sendMessage() {
        Log.d("sender", "Broadcasting message");
        Intent intent = new Intent("webview-filter");

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try This option

***Intent***

..............

You opened the new activity from another activity with **startActivityForResult**. In that case you can just call the f**inishActivity()** function from your code and it'll take you back to the previous activity.

it work only if you start the second activity from main activity

Comment: But SecondActivity is not from MainActivity. So I can't use your solution. It's my fault, because I didn't describe situation much enough... Thank you for answering me. :)